# The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns

Tags: java, jdbc, javadb

I tried to saved data in javadb using JDBC.
It gave an error.

> Error Occured : The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.

This is my JDBC code:

```
try {
    //loading driver 

    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

    //creating connection with the database 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample", "app", "app");

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Student values(?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, Title);
    ps.setString(2, Artist);
    ps.setString(3, Country);
    ps.setString(4, Price);
    ps.setString(5, Year);
    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (i > 0) {
        out.println("You are sucessfully register");
    }
} catch (Exception se) {
    out.println("Error Occured : \n" + se.getLocalizedMessage());
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What part exactly of error message didn't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify the columns you try to *insert*. SQL then assumes you may want to add each column defined for the table *Student*.
I assume there are more columns in the Student table than you have values in your insert statement. That is where the error occurs.

Define the columns you insert the values for explicitly.

```sql
insert into Student (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5) values (?,?,?,?,?)
```

If all other columns are optional or auto-generated it will work that way. Otherwise you will get another error telling you which column is missing.